# Exit For If thextbox null

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I am trying to solve for next loop (exit for) of my project, I have 30 textbox, but sometimes you dont need to fill every textbox, if textbox is blank, sytem takes it zero and it effects our chart results. (I dont want to see zero point on chart)

I thought we I could use exit for but now I cannot see nothing on graph, please help me how can I calculate only filled textboxes.

See my codes here,

```
Dim Guc (59) as decimal

Guc(1) = Val(TextBox5.Text)*Val(Textbox98.Text)
.
.
.

Guc(59) = Val(TextBox42.Text)*Val(Textbox12.Text)


For i = 1 To 59 Step 2

       Dim txt As TextBox = CType(TabControlPanel1.Controls("TextBoxX" & i), TextBox)

       Hız1 = Val(txt.Text) * 5

       Power1 = guc(i) * 3.14 / (30 * 1000) *2

      ChartControl4.Series("Series 1").Points.Add(New SeriesPoint(Hız1, Power1))


Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to exist the loop but to continue your loop if a given textbox is null, something like this:

```
...
    Dim txt As TextBox = CType(TabControlPanel1.Controls("TextBoxX" & i), TextBox)
    If txt Is Nothing Then Continue For 
...
```

OR if your textbox does not become NULL but has 0 as value, you then check for 0 and continue if the value is 0:

```
    Dim txt As TextBox = CType(TabControlPanel1.Controls("TextBoxX" & i), TextBox)
    If Val(txt.Text) = 0 Then Continue For
```

`Continue For` will switch loop control to the next iteration and thus you will traverse all your checkboxes and will add only non-null and non-0 points to the chart.

HTH

Comment: thanks Andrews, I understood it worked as well, but I have one question    I have 16 pcs series, I would like to see only six series in chart, but I select 6 pcs series, I see series7 x axis 0 but y axsis have values, How can I fix this as well ? ChartControl3.Series("Series 1").Points.Add(New SeriesPoint(Val(txt.text), Hız1))

Comment: @emraharslan ummm I may need to see your chart HTML mark up. Let's do this. If my answer helped you to solve the current question, pls accept it (checkbox to left under down arrow). Then post another question with chart markup and the screenshot of what you get. I will then try to help you. SO doesn't like when several questions are mixed.

Comment: @emraharslan I don't see your new questions under `[devexpress]` tag. Are you going to post it soon?

Comment: please look , I submitted another question, related with chart and reports